# Will deleted domain retain PageRank when someone registers it again?

Tags: domain-registration

Just as the title states, will a deleted domain retain PageRank when someone registers it once again?

Answer (score 2):

Nobody can answer this question correctly except Google, but from my 10+ years of SEO experience…

- Yes, It will retain the page rank (link juice), but the page rank (link juice) might slowly lose its importance over the time if the domain is not pointing to any useful website. 
  Google might consider them as a dead link over the period of time.
- If the inbound links for the domains are still active, then Google will consider the page rank based on

  - The number of links pointing to that domain
  - Importance of the inbound links
- But in any case, IMO, If the domain is not used for longtime, certainly there will be a lose in SEO or Link juice.